# pass values in get method as php framework in jsp

Tags: jsp, url

how can I pass values in get method as php framework in jsp: myhost/MyJSPWeb/urlPatterns/var1/var2?
and then get the var1 and var2 value?

Answer (score 0):

In JSP, you can retrieve the parameters from two ways:

1. Using scriptlets ([**NOT RECOMMENDED**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)):

   ```
   <%
       String parameter = request.getParameter("var1");
   %>
   ```
2. Using Expression Language:

   ```
   ${param.var1}
   ```